# How can I run exec() command in background from php-web page centos server

Tags: php, linux, centos

I prepared my setup on ubuntu and everything is working fine on my local server(i.e ubuntu as weel as mint).

But when i transferred my files to centos server .....i am not able to execute exec() or system command in background.( i changed the permission of program too)

I used following command in ubuntu:

```
$pid=system("./programme.exe {$arg1} {$arg2} {$arg3}>output.txt & echo $!");
```

Could anyone explain why not this is not working on centos(in background).......
but 
         system("./programme.exe {$arg1} {$arg2} {$arg3})  ;
 works fine............

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it could be because of system runs a program and redirects the output back. In your command, you redirecting aswell, so maybe php is waiting for the output. Try using exec instead of system.

```
exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
```

Comment: thnks for your reply ......it is working fine. I am running it through web-browser(php).....so I want to know how i can get Pid for this particular job.